# Chess AI with alpha beta algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, chess, alpha-beta-pruning

I have implemented the alpha beta algorithm for my chess game, however it takes a lot of time (minutes for 4-ply) to finally make a rather stupid move.

I've been trying to find the mistake (I assume I made one) for 2 days now, I would very much appreciate some outside input on my code.

getMove function: is called for the root node, it calls alphaBeta function for all it's child nodes (possible moves) and then chooses the move with the highest score.

```
Move AIPlayer::getMove(Board b, MoveGenerator& gen)
{
    // defined constants: ALPHA=-20000 and BETA= 20000
    int alpha = ALPHA; 
    Board bTemp(false); // test Board
    Move BestMov;
    int i = -1; int temp;
    int len = gen.moves.getLength();  // moves is a linked list holding all legal moves
    BoardCounter++; // private attribute of AIPlayer object, counts analyzed boards
    Move mTemp;     // mTemp is used to apply the nextmove in the list to the temporary test Board
    gen.mouvements.Begin();   // sets the list counter to the first element in the list
    while (++i < len && alpha < BETA){
        mTemp = gen.moves.nextElement();
        bTemp.cloneBoard(b);
        bTemp.applyMove(mTemp);
        temp = MAX(alpha, alphaBeta(bTemp, alpha, BETA, depth, MIN_NODE));
        if (temp > alpha){
            alpha = temp;
            BestMov = mTemp;
        }
    }
    return BestMov;
}
```

alphaBeta function:

```
int AIPlayer::alphaBeta(Board b, int alpha, int beta, char depth, bool nodeType)
{
    Move m;
    b.changeSide();
    compteurBoards++;
    MoveGenerator genMoves(b); // when the constructor is given a board, it automatically generates possible moves
    // the Board object has a player attribute that holds the current player
    if (genMoves.checkMate(b, b.getSide(), moves)){ // if the current player is in checkmate
        return 100000;
    }
    else if (genMoves.checkMate(b, ((b.getSide() == BLACK) ? BLACK : WHITE), moves)){ // if the other player is in checkmate
        return -100000;
    }
    else if (!depth){
        return b.evaluateBoard(nodeType);

    }
    else{
        int scoreMove = alpha;
        int best;
        genMoves.moves.Begin();
        short i = -1, len = genMoves.moves.getLength();
        Board bTemp(false);

        if (nodeType == MAX_NODE){
            best = ALPHA;
            while (++i < len){
                bTemp.cloneBoard(b);
                if (bTemp.applyMove(genMoves.moves.nextElement())){ 
                    scoreMove = alphaBeta(bTemp, alpha, beta, depth - 1, !nodeType);
                    best = MAX(best, scoreMove);
                    alpha = MAX(alpha, best);

                    if (beta <= alpha){ 
                        std::cout << "max cutoff" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return scoreMove;
        //return alpha;
        }
        else{
            best = BETA;
            while (++i < len){
                bTemp.cloneBoard(b);
                if (bTemp.applyMove(genMoves.moves.nextElement())){ 
                    scoreMove = alphaBeta(bTemp, alpha, beta, depth - 1, !nodeType);
                    best = MIN(best, scoreMove);
                    beta = MIN(beta, best);
                    if (beta <= alpha){ 
                        std::cout << "min cutoff" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return scoreMove;
            //return beta;
        }
        return meilleur;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I should note that the evaluateBoard only evaluates the mobility of pieces (number of possible moves, capture moves get a higher score depending on the piece captured)

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should ask this on Code Review or Game Development. Here it is off topic.

Comment: Wait, you aren't evaluating the amount of material? Why not? Does your code work if you use a more standard evaluation function?

Comment: I have tried the material evaluation, but boards with different possible moves (but same pieces) all have the exact same value.

Comment: @Burkhard No, Code-Review focus more on like coding style in general. His question is more involved with chess programming theories. For example, one would need hashing and the board itself should not be recreated.

Comment: @Douglas Zare Evaluation is also critical. However, even with a perfect evaluator, we still shouldn't do it for every node in the tree.

Comment: @Student T: Where did I or anyone else say you had to evaluate every node in the tree? Don't say "however" if what you say does not contrast with what I said. I don't see why you mentioned me or my comment.

Comment: First, as it said here don't pass Board object by value. Use pseudonym or pointer. Second use bitboards - commonly used in chess implementations. Third optimize all copy operations within search loop. Forth, use alphabeta search with pruning, but start with simple implementations. If all works well then add more search optimizations methods, such as: move ordering, killer move, null move iterative deepening, hash tables and etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see that you're trying to implement a mini-max algorithm. However, there is something in the code that makes me suspicious. We'll compare the code with the open-source Stockfish chess engine. Please refer to the search algorithm at https://github.com/mcostalba/Stockfish/blob/master/src/search.cpp

**1.  Passing Board b by value**

You have this in your code:

> alphaBeta(Board b, int alpha, int beta, char depth, bool nodeType)

I don't know what exactly "Board" is. But it doesn't look right to me. Let's look at Stockfish:

> Value search(Position& pos, Stack* ss, Value alpha, Value beta, Depth
>   depth, bool cutNode)

The position object is **passed by reference** in Stockfish. If "Board" is a class, the program will need to make a new copy everytime the alpha-beta function is called. In chess, when we have to evaluate many number of nodes, this is obviously unacceptable.

**2. No hashing**

Hashing is done in Stockfish as:

> ttValue = ttHit ? value_from_tt(tte->value(), ss->ply) : VALUE_NONE;

Without hashing, you'll need to evaluate the same position again and again and again and again. You won't go anywhere without hashing implemented.

**3. Checking for checkmate**

Probably not the most significant slow-down, but we should never check for checkmate in every single node. In Stockfish:

```
// All legal moves have been searched. A special case: If we're in check
// and no legal moves were found, it is checkmate.
if (InCheck && bestValue == -VALUE_INFINITE)
    return mated_in(ss->ply); // Plies to mate from the root
```

This is done **AFTER** all possible moves are searched. We do it because we usually have many more non-checkmates node than checkmate-nodes.

**4. Board bTemp(false);**

This looks like a major slow-down. Let's take at Stockfish:

> ```
>   // Step 14. Make the move
>   pos.do_move(move, st, ci, givesCheck);
> ```

You should not create a temporary object in every node (creating an object of bTemp). The machine would need to allocate some stack space to save bTemp. This could be a serious performance penalty in particular if bTemp is not a primary variable (ie, not likely be cached by the processor). Stockfish simply modifies the internal data-structure without creating a new one.

**5. bTemp.cloneBoard(b);**

Similar to 4, even worse, this is done for every move in the node.

**6. std::cout << "max cutoff" << std::endl;**

Maybe it's hard to believe, printing to a terminal is much slower than processing. Here you're creating a potential slow-down that the string would need to be saved to an IO buffer. The function might (I'm not 100% sure) even block your program until the text is shown on the terminal. Stockfish only does it for statistic summary, definitely not everytime when you have a fail-high or fail-low.

**7. Not sorting the PV move**

Probably not something that you want to do before addressing the other issues. In Stockfish, they have:

> std::stable_sort(RootMoves.begin() + PVIdx, RootMoves.end());

This is done for every iteration in an iterative-deepening framework.

Comment: Hi Student T, thank you for your input. 
I have been working on implementing the transposition table and move ordering for the past 2 days, it's still not done yet, but I expect i'll see a difference. 
I have also taken your advice, and applied the move directly to the board without cloning it, in fact I'm working on removing all the unnecessary pass by value, the program speed increased significantly due to that.

Comment: Good work! You'll master chess programming in no-time. If you're interested, please follow discussions on talkchess.com where all engine programmers go including myself. Also, please consider to accept my answer.

Comment: I'm using bitboards and a custom linked list to store moves. For move ordering, I have an attribute for the Move class that holds a score for the move, when a move is found, a score is assigned to it based on whether it is a capture, and which piece captured which and so on, then it's added to the list in it's sorted position to eliminate the need to sort the list after all moves are added.

Comment: I'm still having some trouble with the evaluation function, I have tried material evaluation and now added mobility also (mobility score for each piece is the sum of the scores of all possible Moves made by said piece). 
If you don't mind, what would you recommend I use?

Comment: While I don't think Stockfish does what you do, what you're doing is also good enough.

Comment: I think you should start a new question. This way, I and others can come and help you. Here, it's only me and you. Other programmers only know when they see a new question. Please accept one of the answers and start a new question. I'll post when I see the new question.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thank you for your assistance.
I'll try and work on the evaluation function for the rest of the day, if by then I still need some help, I'll start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I am only going to address the runtime cost problem of your algorithm, because I don't know the implementation details of your board evaluation function.

In order to keep things as simple as possible, I will assume the worst case for the algorithm.

The getMove function makes len1 calls to the alphaBeta function, which in turn makes len2 calls to itself, which in turn makes len3 calls to itself and so on until depth reaches 0 and the recursion stops. 
Because of the worst case assumption, let's say n = max(len1, len2, ...), so you have

n * n * n * ... * n calls to alphaBeta with number of multiplications depending on depth d, which leads to n^d calls to alphaBeta which means that you have an exponential runtime behavior. This is ultra slow and only beaten by factorial runtime behavior.

I think you should take a look at the Big O notation for that purpose and try to optimize your algorithm accordingly to get much faster results.

Best regards,
OPM

Comment: Hi OPM, thank you for your input.
The alpha beta pruning is an optimization of the minimax algorithm where the tree branches that can't improve the solution are not analyzed, so that reduces the number of nodes to be analyzed significantly.
Even though it is exponential, I don't think that's the problem since it's still supposed to be faster than it is right now.

Comment: Hi user34853, I know the alpha-beta pruning for minimax and one common problem of this algorithm is a badly ordered moveset. In the worst case, the cut off will take place at the last examined node, which makes it the same as the minimax algorithm again. In order to avoid this, there are several things you can do. The simplest method would be to store so-called killer moves that produced a cut off and evaluate them first. Another common optimization would be a transposition table to store analyzed positions to prevent multiple analyses of the same board. Best regards, OPM

Comment: By the way, have a look at your ?-operator in the alphaBeta function :)

Comment: Hi OPM, I've done some more research and I believe you are right, I will add the killer heuristic and transposition table.
Good catch on the ?-operator. ^^
Thank you again for your assistance.

Comment: It's certainly correct that a killer move and sorting a PV move would help. But a plain alpha-beta still shouldn't be that bad. See my answer.